# I am getting: /tikz.code.tex:473 Undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf

When ever I copy and paste code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/ such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz \draw plot [smooth cycle] coordinates {(0,0) (1,0.1) (2,0.3) (2,1.4) (1.5,2.5) (0.8,2.5) (0.3,1.2) (-0.2,0.6) } node at (1,1) {Area};
\tikz \draw plot [smooth,tension=1.2] coordinates {(0,1) (0.75,0.5) (1.5,0.9) (2,0) (2.5,0)} node at (1,0) {Line};

\end{document}
```

and try to run it I am getting the following error (see attached image):

[image]

this was never happening in the past...

Comment: Is the error caused by that code for you? It works fine with me.

Comment: @alennano hi, this error error has never happened before, just today...if I paste this code as a snippet in one of my older files, there is no error and all goes well... I wonder why this is happening... What do you think?

Comment: It my be some other portion of the document causing the problem. Block out portions and run the code to see which block contains the error.

Comment: Listen to Leucippus: he knows of the significance of the smallest of things things....

Comment: Why is the file `tikz.code.tex` input from the current directory?

Comment: I have been using TexShop to compile the tex files, in the past i have never had any problems such as:

Comment: In the past I have never had any problems such as: ./tikz.code.tex:473: Undefined control sequence. \pgf@decl@arrow@means ...mp ]\pgf@arrows@invertto 
                                                  
l.473 \tikz@set@pointed{\pgf@arrows@invertto}{to} ? This happens nowadays not only when I copy and paste snippets of code from http://tex.stackechange.com/ but also when I even type directly the lines of code into TexShop... I reinstalled the entire Tex package with TexShop, the error persists, even when I run the command line: pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex

Comment: Problem solved: TexShop was simply saying that the folder where the tex file was contained too many files. I created an empty folder and moved the tex file there and the 473 error disappeared... Thanks guys for the comments anyway...

Comment: I don’t think that the problem were the too may files, but rather the fact that one of them was named `tikz.code.tex`, thus obscuring the “right” `tikz.code.tex` file found in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/`.

Comment: Gustavo you are right... There was a file like that... So, I deleted the tikz.code.tex file from the folder where I had my *.tex files and now everything works just fine without any errors. Thank you.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3):

`tikz.code.tex` is the name of the file that implements the TikZ frontend.  Its standard TDS location is inside `<TEX_ROOT>/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/`, but the OP had a file by that same name inside the same directory as the file (s)he was compiling.  There is clear evidence of this in the excerpt of the transcript file (s)he posted, that contained the lines:

```
(./tikz.code.tex
./tikz.code.tex:473: Undefined control sequence.
```

Actually, the first line suffices to identify the file: indeed, every time TeX begins to read from a new input source, it writes into the transcript an opening parenthesis followed by the full pathname of the file it is starting to read from (and writes the corresponding closing parenthesis when it stops reading from that file).  You can see that, in this case, the full pathname begins with `./` (that is, the current directory).

I don’t know what this spurious `tikz.code.tex` file contained, nor why the OP had a file by that name in her/his current directory, but for sure that was not a copy (or an up-to-date copy) of the original `tikz.code.tex` file (in which line 473 does not look like that).  Now, normally the search paths of TeX are organized in such a way that the current directory takes precedence over any directory that TeX searches for input files; thus, the spurious `tikz.code.tex` file was loaded *instead* of the correct one, and, being evidently incorrect or outdated, it triggered the error.  Of course, this happened only when compiling from that particular directory.